# Get data from User table and extended User table

Tags: python, django

I have extended user model in Django.

The model for extending user is as follows :

```
class Member(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(to=User)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    match_code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.ForeignKey(to=Country, null=True)
    language = models.ForeignKey(to=Language)
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    main_email = models.EmailField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Now I want to check if user exist matching email from `User` table and number from `Member` table.

How can I do that?

Right now I'm doing this as follows :

```
email = "some@email.com"
user = User.objects.get(email=email)
member = Member.objects.get(user_id=user.id)
```

Thus I get first data from User table and then I get everything from member table.

But is there better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will do that check:

```
User.objects.filter(email=email, member__number=number).exists()
```

You can retrieve these members via:

```
Member.objects.get(user_id__email=email, number=number)
```

Two things:

- do NOT call your `ForeignKey` `'user_id'`, call it `'user'`. The field `user_id` will then be created automatically.
- If there should not be multiple members per user, make `user` a `OneToOneField`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the member in one go, if that's what you want:

```
Member.objects.get(user_id__email=email)
```

Note that your foreign key really should be called just `user`, not `user_id`.

Answer (score 0):

If user exists:

```
if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
    member = Member.objects.get(user_id=User.objects.get(email=email).id)
```